# FOSUserBundle allowing 'Anon' user to access `/admin`

Tags: symfony, admin, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOSUserBundle and am successfully creating users in my database. However, I'm trying to log users in and only have `ROLE_ADMIN` users access `/admin` by following the [Symfony security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#initial-security-yml-setup-authentication) walk-through.

However, even without having figured out logging users in, when I try to access `localhost/app_dev.php/admin` I am able to access it as the "Anon" user. Below are my security.yml and controller files:

*app/config/security.yml*

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager 

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

*src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php*

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function AdminAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('default/admin.html.twig', array(
            'title' => 'Welcome Admin!!'
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with FOSUserBundle however your `access_control` entry is for the path `/admin/` - note the trailing slash whereas your example `localhost/app_dev.php/admin` doesn't. If you remove that from your `access_control` entry or change your routes then this should work as expected.

E.g.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```